# How to find duplicates in lucene documents?

Tags: lucene

In lucene

1. How can we find two documents having same ids?
2. How can we find two documents having similar names(with some spelling mistake in     one of the name)?

Answer (score 0):

if your document have any field like hashvalue, you can use Duplicate Filter and avoid duplicate document while searching.